# Codeigniter Many to Many Error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, relational-database

I have 3 tables ...

instructors, classes and instructor_teach

I want to display a list of classes that the instructor teaches

I have been using tutorials and the like to try and work this out so if my code is messy i do apologize.

Model...

```
function getMemberPrograms($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('instructor_teach');
    $this->db->join('instructor_teach', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
    $this->db->join('classes', 'instructor_teach.program_id = classes.id');
    $this->db->where('instructor_teach.instructors_id', $id);
    return;
}
```

In the controller i just have a print_r statement to see what the results are but at the moment i am getting

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Table/alias: 'instructor_teach' non unique
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM (`instructor_teach`, `classes`) JOIN `instructor_teach`
> ON `instructors`.`id` = `instructor_teach`.`instructor_id` JOIN
> `classes` ON `instructor_teach`.`program_id` = `classes`.`id` WHERE
> `instructor_teach`.`instructors_id` = '1'
> ```
>
> Filename: C:/wamp/www/fitness/application/models/members_model.php
>
> Line Number: 16

what i want is an array that has all the information from the classes the instructor teaches so

instructor 1 teaches class 1, class 2

array would return

class 1.name
class 1.description

class 2.name
class 2.description

etc..

I hope this makes sense as i am still getting to terms with this

Many Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I think you are joining the table `instructor_teach` to it self `instructor_teach`

take a look:

```
$this->db->from('instructor_teach');
$this->db->join('instructor_teach', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
```

I think it should be:

```
$this->db->from('instructor_teach');
$this->db->join('instructors', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('instructor_teach');
    $this->db->join('instructor_teach', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
    $this->db->join('classes', 'instructor_teach.program_id = classes.id');
    $this->db->where('instructor_teach.instructors_id', $id);
```

First is you select to table instructor_teach then afterwards you want to join it again with table instructor_teach where in it will give you a error.

And one thing also if you can select only important columns from each tables is much more okay.

I think the query should look like this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('instructors');
$this->db->join('instructor_teach', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
$this->db->join('classes', 'instructor_teach.program_id = classes.id');
$this->db->where('instructor_teach.instructors_id', $id);
```

Comment: I still get this error with this change Error Number: 1066

Table/alias: 'classes' non unique

SELECT * FROM (`instructors`, `classes`) JOIN `instructor_teach` ON `instructors`.`id` = `instructor_teach`.`instructor_id` JOIN `classes` ON `instructor_teach`.`program_id` = `classes`.`id` WHERE `instructor_teach`.`instructors_id` = '1'

Filename: C:/wamp/www/fitness/application/models/members_model.php

Line Number: 16

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this correct, but try to change the first join with instructor table

```
    $this->db->join('instructor_teach', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
```

to

```
    $this->db->join('instructor', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
```

---

**try this**

```
function getMemberPrograms($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('instructor_teach');
    $this->db->join('instructor', 'instructors.id = instructor_teach.instructor_id');
    $this->db->join('classes', 'instructor_teach.program_id = classes.id');
    $this->db->where('instructor_teach.instructors_id', $id);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting this error with this change... Error Number: 1066

Table/alias: 'classes' non unique

SELECT * FROM (`instructor_teach`, `classes`) JOIN `instructor` ON `instructors`.`id` = `instructor_teach`.`instructor_id` JOIN `classes` ON `instructor_teach`.`program_id` = `classes`.`id` WHERE `instructor_teach`.`instructors_id` = '1'

Filename: C:/wamp/www/fitness/application/models/members_model.php

Line Number: 16